# Json Object to Sqlite Database in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, touchjson

I want to push the fetched data of json file to database. Can anyone suggests some solution?

Comment: Hi rckoenes Till now i am able to get the data from json file to a dictionary and this data i want to push into the sqlite datbase.
So thats all i have done ,but not able to get any further clear picture regarding this .

Answer (score 1):

1) First of all you might guess what really you do want to do with that data, because:

- you could use things like FMDB https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb.git and store that JSON as string and get it reparsed every time you need it;
- also you can use Mogenerator tool https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator.git and smth like MagicalRecord library [*https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord.git*] to easily fetch data in n out;
- and finally, there's CoreData if you like Apple's choise.